# Converted PDF is downloadable on both mobile (375px) and lg devices (1024px) but it is not visible on mobile devices. It is not clickable on mobile

Tags: python, django, html-to-pdf, xhtml2pdf

This is my views.py to convert html template to pdf

```py
from datetime import datetime
from io import BytesIO
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import  HttpResponse
from frontend.views.task_shifts import valid_task_date
from frontend.views.utils import *
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from django.template.loader import get_template

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf_path = os.path.join(
        settings.BASE_DIR, 'pdf_files', 'Rating_report.pdf')

    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=result)
    if pisa_status.err:
        return HttpResponse('We had some error')

    with open(pdf_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(result.getvalue())

    return pdf_path


@login_required(login_url='login_user')
def get_pdf(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated == False or request.session.get('station_code') is None or request.session['station_code'] is None:

        logout(request)
        return redirect("login_user")

    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        date1 = request.POST.get('date')
        date = datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

        context = {'date': date }

        pdf_path = render_to_pdf('front/pdf/pdf.html', context)
        pdf_file = os.path.basename(pdf_path)

        with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as f:
            response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = f'inline; filename="{pdf_file}"'

        return response

    else:
        messages = []
        messages.append('Enter date to see pdf')
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'messages': messages})
```

and my html template is

```html
{% load custom %} {% load static %} {% block body %}
<h1> pdf demo</h1>
<p>for : {{date}}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

and the form to submit the date to views.py is

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalForPdf" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                      <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Select Date</h5>
                                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                          </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <form action="{% url 'getpdf' %}" method="POST">
                                                {% csrf_token %}
                                                <input type="date" name="date"  value='$date' required  >
                                                <input type="submit" value="submit">
                                            </form>
                                        
                                        </div>
                                       
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
```

It is working fine on mobile devices but when I try to submit the form on mobile device the pdf is not showing it just shows white screen. and if we open it on mobile using oprt like
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` then btn is not clicking it just runs the function in background.

Does anybody now why it is happening?  I tried few methods but none are working!

I tried using weayprint and reportlab but the issue presist in them too!
I am using python 3.9, django 4.15 and xHTML2PDF of 0.2.8